# Is non tangential velocity can produce angular momentum

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics

I want to know what happens to angular momentum when velocity is non tangential, and if non tangential velocity have tangential component and some radial component, then how we got

L = Iw

Where I is moment of inertia and w is angular velocity at certain time (say't')

[image: Courtesy HC Verma (concept of physics VOL- I)]

Answer (score 0):

This was the angular momentum for a rigid body, and the definition of moment of inertia relativ of a fixed  axis, all points rotate around this axis, so there is no tangential velocity except the whole body is moving in some direction. So what you ask does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Angular momentum is $\mathbf L = \mathbf r \times \mathbf p$, where $\mathbf p$ is the linear momentum.

A planet in an eliptic orbit around the sun has constant angular momentum for example. And as you can see from the definition of the cross product, the radial component of $\mathbf p$ doesn't contribute to it.

The formula $L = I\omega$ is specific for rigid bodies, and in this case it is not possible to have any radial component of $\mathbf p$.

Answer (score 0):

For a rigid body not rotating about a fixed axis things are not so simple.  For any particle in the body, its velocity v is the vector ω x r where r is the distance from the origin of the rotating body axes (a fixed point of rotation or the center of mass) to the location of the particle.  The linear momentum p = v/m of each particle of mass m in the body is only considered in deriving the formula L=Iω by summing over the angular momenta for each particle m(r x v). In general, the angular momentum vector L=Iω for a rigid body where I is the inertia tensor, and ω is the angular velocity vector.  Typically, I and ω are expressed with components along the principal axes in the body that rotate with the body.  L is not parallel to ω if ω is not along a principal axis  (Typically, the Eulerian angles are used to provide components along the space (fixed) axes.)  The translational motion of the rigid body is typically considered as motion of the center of mass and the linear momentum p is that of the center of mass determined from the net external force on the body.